# Second hand smartphone with Android updates for the next few years

Tags: android, smartphones

I would like to buy a smartphone for less than 150 €. I like the idea more to get an older smartphone which was great at that time than a new and cheap one for a few reasons, e.g. sustainability.

But there is one big problem with old smartphone: There are no updates. Even the Samsung Galaxy S8 seems not to be updated anymore. Are there manufacturers who guarantee updates for the next few years? Or is there an easy way to install an Android distribution which is updated for a few years. I always had bad experiences with those not official distributions in the past, but it was some years ago.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Motorola Moto G30 checks all of the boxes, except its not second hand. Its cheap (currently €150 at mediamarkt.nl) and will get updates for at least 1.5 years from now and after that, you can install LineageOS for another 2 years of updates.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be best cheap phone at the moment...